# PHP Contact Form Advice

Tags: php, forms

I have built a contact page for my website, and when I test it out, the only thing that appears is the message.  There is no contact information, except for the url of my hosting site.  Any advice on how I could fix this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<form action="contact.php" class="form-style-9" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
<input type="text" name="first_name" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="First Name" />
 <input type="text" name="last_name" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Last Name" />


</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="phone" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="Phone" />
<input type="email" name="email" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Email" />
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="subject" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Subject" />
</li>
<li>
<textarea name="message" class="field-style" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</li>
<li>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];

 $to = "kyle@kylenarovich.com";
 $subject = "New Message";

 mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $first_name . $last_name);


echo "Thank you for contacting me. I will be in touch with you very soon."; 





?>
```

Again, any advice and help would be greatly appreciated, as the site is live and if someone contacts me, I have no way to get back to them if they don't put there info in the message.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: "when I test it out, the only thing that appears is the message" That's all your PHP code does. It sends an email and prints the message.

Comment: How would I make it so it displays all the info in the form?

Comment: Echo it out too. `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);` I'd suggest starting with a basic PHP tutorial.

Comment: OK, thank you for the help!

Comment: Rather than POSTing to a completely different page, post the form to the same page that displays the form ( though it is currently appearing to be HTML rather than php but that could just be because of an htaccess rule ) and display whatever messages you want after the POST has been submitted. You can test for this using $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' etc

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && array_key_exists( 'form_submitted',$_POST )){
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $to = "kyle@kylenarovich.com";
        $subject = "New Message";

        $res=@mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $first_name . $last_name);
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="contact.php" class="form-style-9" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="First Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Last Name" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="Phone" />
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Email" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Subject" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <textarea name="message" class="field-style" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
                    <input type='hidden' name='form_submitted' value='true' />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && array_key_exists( 'form_submitted',$_POST ) ){
                    if( $res==true ) echo 'Thanks for submitting the form... etc etc';
                    else echo 'Oops! Failed to send email';
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why that was marked down - there is an explaination above in the comments - the code above was just to indicate what was meant.